# Could I set flag "barrier=0" when using SSD?

Tags: linux, ext4, ssd

I'm using ext4 filesystem in SSD,when mounting SSD,could I use flag "barrier=0"?
I knew this flag is safe for BBU（battery backup unit）,but is it safe for SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, but it's same safety as rotating rust. just because ssd has no moving parts doesn't make it invulnerable to power outage.
A small caveat: depending on the model, it's possible the ssd has enough capacitors to finish transfer of any cached data to non-volatile storage, but this is never guaranteed.
Of course, if the ssd has no cache, all writes are synchronous, so barriers has no meaning.